# Anular el valor de una propiedad CSS

Tags: css3

Estoy editando un archivo CSS, quiero anular el valor de esa propiedad, pero no quiero fijar un nuevo valor.

Tengo el archivo A, **que no puedo editar**.

```
.menu a {
  padding: 20x;
}
```

Así que ahora creo otra hoja de estilos, pero si pongo

```
.menu a {
  padding: 0;
}
```

No se ve como yo quiero. Una opción es colocar otro valor, como `padding: 5px;`, pero busco una alternativa. Cuando desmarco esa propiedad en el inspector de Safari, las cosas quedan como lo espero.

### Ejemplo:

```css
.caja {
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
}

.caja {
  padding: 20px;
}


/* solo cambiar las líneas de abajo */
/* no vale padding: 40px; */
.caja {

}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  Quiero que el padding vuelva a ser 40 anulando el <code>padding: 20px;</code>
</div>
```

#### ¿Cómo puedo desactivar la propiedad `padding` desde otra hoja de estilos?

> En este [ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/unset) se logra el efecto usando distintas clases y elementos, usando `unset`. Tal vez no sea posible con las condiciones que pretendo.

Comment: Has probado a poner inherit? Lo digo porque si cuando desmarcas se ve como esperas, lo mas probable es que esté heredando el estilo que deseas.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el segundo fichero está linkeado? Si no tienes más clases que afecten a ese menú, la opción que usas de `padding: 0` debería de funcionar.

Comment: Hola @JoseFG, podrías elaborar una respuesta usando `inherit`? Creo que nunca la he usado.

Comment: @Error404, se ve horrible cuando pongo `padding: 0;`.

Comment: @toledano ¿Podrías ponernos un ejemplo en el que se reproduzca tu error? ¿O cual es el objetivo? Realmente poniendo `padding: 0` es lo mismo que quitarlo desde el inspector.

Comment: Es el tema de mi [blog](https://yo.toledano.org), el submenú de editorial. Solo se resuelve desmarcando una propiedad tipo `.genesis-nav .sub-menu .a`

Comment: @toledano Realmente cuando he abierto tu blog no veo nada raro en ese submenú. De hecho, me marca como que la propiedad `padding: 20px` no la está teniendo en cuenta. ¿Has probado a borrar la cache y recargar la página? Puede ser que te haya guardado los cambios que tenías antes en la caché y por eso se te esté viendo erróneamente.

Comment: @toledano Acabo de ver el ejemplo que has puesto pero no entiendo esto `/* solo cambiar las líneas de abajo */
/* no vale padding: 40px; */`. ¿Por qué no puedes poner padding: 40px?

Comment: Porque quiero saber si es posible hacerlo, no colocar otro valor, sino anular el valor anterior.

Comment: @toledano Vale, he publicado una respuesta. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: @toledano Lo he conseguido asignando un id al div: `<div class="caja" id="nueva-caja">` y luego en el CSS:  `#nueva-caja {  padding: 40px;
}` en este caso el `id` tiene prioridad por lo que se aplicará todo lo que pongas en ese bloque independientemente del lugar donde esté en el CSS, lo he probado poniéndolo al inicio y al final y funciona. He publicado una respuesta para que quede también esa posibilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como lo tienes planteado no lo puedes resetear ya que se asigno anteriormente `padding: 20px;`

La única forma es poner `padding: 40px;` de nuevo:

```
.caja {
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
}

.caja {
  padding: 20px;
}

.caja {
  padding: 40px; // Nuevo valor asignado
}
```

Es así como funciona `CSS` Hojas de Estilo en [**Cascada**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade).

Answer (score 3):

Si al desmarcarlo lo ves como deseas, seguramente estés heredando la propiedad de la forma que la deseas de un antecesor. Si utilizas `padding: inherit` seguramente obtengas el estilo deseado.

Comment: Jose para mejorar tu respuesta intenta añadir un snippet de codigo como el que usa el autor de la pregunta para mostrar como funciona tu solucion. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es anular un estilo, es decir, recuperar el valor por defecto que tiene ese estilo en concreto, en este caso el `padding`, que haya sido modificado anteriormente (lo mismo que desmarcar el estilo desde el inspector de Google Chrome) deberías usar el valor `initial`.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
.caja {
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
}

.caja {
  padding: 20px;
}

.caja {
  padding: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  Quiero que el padding vuelva a ser 40 anulando el <code>padding: 20px;</code>
</div>
```

Comment: `initial` hace que el padding sea `0`.

Comment: @toledano Sí, ya que es valor que tiene el `padding` por defecto. Es lo que he entendido cuando dices `anular` el estilo. ¿O que se tendría que ver?

Comment: Mira este ejemplo, aqui lo logran usando otras clases y elementos: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/unset algo así es lo que busco.

Comment: @toledano Realmente si te fijas en la siguiente frase la propiedad que usan (`unset`) es una mezcla de las propiedades `initial` e `inherit`: `The unset CSS keyword is the combination of the initial and inherit keywords.` y lo que hace básicamente es heredar de su elemento padre el estilo (si es que está definido) o lo que es lo mismo utilizarán el valor `inherit` y si no está definido ningún estilo que afecte desde su elemento padre entonces toma el valor por defecto, por lo que tendrá en cuenta la propiedad `initial`. Simplemente lo que han hecho ha sido juntar dos propiedades en una sola.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas `important` se solucionaria tu problema de styles

```css
.caja {
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
}

.caja {
  padding: 20px;
}


/* solo cambiar las líneas de abajo */
/* no vale padding: 40px; */
.caja {
      padding: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  Quiero que el padding vuelva a ser 40 anulando el <code>padding: 20px;</code>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, pero estás cambiando las líneas de arriba, solo puedo cambiar las líneas de abajo.

Comment: @toledano edite mi respuesta, espero que funcione

Comment: Claro que funciona, solo pensaba que `inherit`, `initial` o `unset` podrían hacer la magia.

Comment: @toledano El problema es que _no puedes editar tu hoja A_... Aunque el uso de `important` no es recomendado y considerado una mala práctica en muchos casos (ver https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) en tu caso es la solución más simple... puesto que el valor en A no está marcado como tal. Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que hicieras cargar primero tu hoja A y luego tu hoja B. Al final la propiedad tendría el valor de B.

Answer (score 1):

Hay otra manera de hacerlo, a condición de que tengas acceso al HTML.

En el html le asignas una propiedad `id`al elemento, aquí la he llamado `nueva-caja`:

```
<div class="caja" id="nueva-caja">
  Quiero que el padding vuelva a ser 40 anulando el <code>padding: 20px;</code><br>Aquí el div tiene <code>class="caja" id="nueva-caja"</code>
</div>
```

Luego en el CSS:

```
#nueva-caja {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

En CSS el `id` tendrá **prioridad** sobre el nombre de la clase, como podrás ver en el ejemplo (he añadido un color de fondo azul para apreciar que funciona).

Si pones el código anterior al principio del CSS también funcionará, lo he probado :)

```css
.caja {
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
}

.caja {
  padding: 20px;
}

#nueva-caja {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
Con id:
<div class="caja" id="nueva-caja">
  Quiero que el padding vuelva a ser 40 anulando el <code>padding: 20px;</code><br>Aquí el div tiene <code>class="caja" id="nueva-caja"</code>
</div>

<hr />
Sin id:
<div class="caja">
  Quiero que el padding vuelva a ser 40 anulando el <code>padding: 20px;</code><br>Aquí el div tiene solamente <code>class="caja"</code>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente alternativa. Y no es que no tenga acceso, es un menú de WordPress, generado automáticamente. Y tiene un tema padre, un hijo, y otra hoja de estilos más. No voy a modificar el tema padre ni el hijo (porque se pierden en las actualizaciones) solo el tercero.

Comment: Dependiendo del framework que uses, si usas alguno (Thesis, Génesis) o el mismo WP, si quieres optar por esa alternativa tendrías que asignarle un id desde el editor de plantillas. Pero conociendo ahora el contexto, lo que yo uso para estos casos en mi WP es el custom.css (Thesis) allí añado los cambios al final del archivo. Lo edito por FTP, aunque se puede editar desde WP con el Custom CSS. Y claro, tengo un script de ssh que me hace copia de ese archivo cada cierto tiempo, aunque Thesis cuando actualiza conserva intacto el css

Comment: Uso Genesis Framework y la técnica es la misma. Y al final usé la alternativa de la respuesta seleccionada, que no usa `!important` y quedó como yo quería. Por cierto, un clon del tema clásico de Thesis, hecho en Genesis.

Comment: En realidad lo que hace Thesis y creo que Genesis (pues no lo uso pero sospecho que se parecen) es lo que se hace en la respuesta marcada, o sea, agregar un nuevo valor CSS a la propiedad, el cual queda al final del archivo CSS que se carga en la página. Sólo que en la práctica (imagino) es un método más lento, ya que aplica primero una propiedad y luego otra que encuentra al final del archivo.